# xmltask error encoding

Tags: ant, encoding, xmltask

I´m trying to get the value of node in the xml file. I observed that value is wrong. I´m belive that problem is the encoding. Someaone can help me ? below is my code:

**In xml File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<projects>
    <project>
       <application>Padrão</application> <!-- The problem is the character ~ -->
       <name>padrao</name>
       <icon>c:\buffer</icon>
       <market>br.com.tls.test</market>
  </project>
</projects>
```

**My ant code**

```
<xmltask source="config.xml"  encoding="UTF-8">
    <call path="//project">
       <param name="name" path="name/text()" />
       <param name="market" path="market/text()" />
       <param name="icon" path="icon/text()" />
       <param name="application"  path="application/text()" />

          <actions>
             <echo message="@{application}" />
             <init-release name="@{name}" market="@{market}" icon="@{icon}"  application="@{application}"/>
          </actions>
     </call>
</xmltask>
```

**Result**

```
[echo]:    padr#o
```

**expected**

```
[echo]:    padrão
```

**Solution**

I changing the file to UTF-8 and I´d sucess in the replace.

Comment: If your question is solved, you should post an answer and accept it instead of putting *solved* into your title

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used xmltask, but echo task also has encoding property, have you tried setting that as well?

e.g.  `<echo message="@{application}" encoding="UTF-8" />`